# Wordpress keeps showing mobile version on Internet Explorer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, theme-twenty-fourteen, masonry

I have wordpress 4.3.1 installed on the intranet with a standard theme TwentyFourteen. When I use Firefox and Chrome to view the website, everything works exactly like it should.

However, on IE9 and IE11, the website is only shown in mobile version regardless of client width, the main navi dropdown does not work, and the layout is a bit off. Overall, it looks like something is not loading correct.

When I check F12 Developer Tools, it gives Javascript errors for a bunch of plugins. Fine, I deactivated them all, but there is still masonry.min.js and jquery.masonry.min.js.

Now, disabling all the plugins is not a solution. How can I keep my plugins and still make IE work?

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue it was because I was missing something from the `<head>`.

Below is the head from the [basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) on the bootstrap website.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```